# Why use debug.keystore?

Tags: android, keystore

I know the difference between a release keystore and the default debug.keystore, but why use the debug.keystore at all?

It is said debug.keystore is used during development but I don't see any advantages of that, only disadvantages. When integrating stuff like Facebook and Google Maps you need to generate a hash out of it.

Disadvantages:

- You always need to add at least two hashes
- Two different machines could have different debug.keystores I believe so my colleagues could have problems in the app when building the app themselves.

In my point of view you can always use the release keystore just fine during development.

Comment: For some developers, the keystore used to sign production builds is a very sensitive piece of information. Keeping that information on their computer at all times, even if it's in an encrypted volume, could be undesirable. So going through the process of production-signing every test build might just be too much of a hassle, compared to just signing them with a debug key that can be kept on their development machines at all times.

Comment: @Michael ok thanks I understand. If you put it in an answer I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: I think it's sad and unfair I got those downvotes because I really think it is a valid question, because I couldn't find an answer here or via Google, and there are a lot of low quality and duplicate questions of amature developers here not even getting that much downvotes

Comment: @IvoBeckers I hope you won't let this get you down. Lots of amateurs will upvote other amateur questions because either they were wondering the same thing or simply out of empathy, people hunting for rep will upvote bad questions to try to harvest easy rep with answers to easy/dupe questions, then you have sock-puppets, voting rings etc... Rep on SO is completely meaningless IMHO. I'm out of votes for today, but I'll try to come back here tomorrow to vote it back up because despite the troll vote, I think it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I find the question interesting. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be other reasons for using a debug keystore, but I'm just going to mention one that's security related:

For some developers, the keystore used to sign production builds is a very sensitive piece of information. Keeping that information on their hard drive at all times, even if it's in an encrypted volume, could be undesirable. If your app is a game with a hundred users, having someone else obtaining your production keystore perhaps isn't the end of the world. But if your app is an online banking app with a million users, then having your keystore stolen suddenly becomes a pretty big deal.

Going through the process of production-signing every test build might just be too much of a hassle, compared to signing the test builds with a debug key that can be kept on your development machines at all times.